# was(how to call javascript on robotframework) On robotframework, how to pass a string to variable which generated by javascript

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I am a green hand for coding. Here I want to use robotframework, selenium2library to test my company's software. I need to simulate click table operation.But there is a problem about the table's Xpath, it is dynamic, so I need to use java script to find the Xpath of table, then pass the xpath which generated by js to a variable, then "click element ${variable}"

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***


*** Keywords ***
Select added lsp
   Execute Javascript   variable=function getId(){
                        var  resultid = 'error';
                        $("#gridview-1275 table").each(function(){
                            var value = $(this).find('tr:eq(0)').find('td:eq(0)').text().replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g,'')+$(this).find('tr:eq(0)').find('td:eq(1)').text().replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/g,'');
                            if(value=="222vmx102-11"){
                                resultid = "//*[@id=\""+$(this).attr("id")+"\"]";
                                             }
                                                     });
                         return resultid;
                        }

 click element    ${variable}
```

but I got error,Here is the traceback:

```
> 15:06:18.139  INFO    Executing JavaScript: variable=function getId(){    
> 15:06:18.141  DEBUG   POST
> http://127.0.0.1:63649/session/761829a0232d76a80dfb1dfce7546369/execute
> {"sessionId": "761829a0232d76a80dfb1dfce7546369", "args": [],
> "script": "variable=function getId(){"}    15:06:18.163   DEBUG   Finished
> Request    15:06:19.806   FAIL    WebDriverException: Message: unknown error:
> Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]
>     at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:875:140)
>     at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:808:34)
>     at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:664:21)   (Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.86)   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457
> (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1
> x86_64) 15:06:19.807  DEBUG   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "<string>", line 2, in execute_javascript   File
> "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library\keywords\keywordgroup.py",
> line 15, in _run_on_failure_decorator
>     return method(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library\keywords\_javascript.py",
> line 97, in execute_javascript
>     return self._current_browser().execute_script(js)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 423, in execute_script
>     {'script': script, 'args':converted_args})['value']   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library\webdrivermonkeypatches.py",
> line 11, in execute
>     result = self._base_execute(driver_command, params)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
> line 195, in execute
>     self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
> line 170, in check_response
>     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
```

Comment: can you show the full stacktrace? Also, this doesn't seem to be your actual code because there are syntax errors. You are creating a keyword with the very unusual name of `${1111} = Execute JavaScript function getId(){`. You may think you're calling javascript, but that whole string is in the place where robot expects a keyword name.

Comment: Yes, I want to call javascript. more to the point, I am trying to call javascript, because I don't know how to do it, forgive me, I am just a learner about robotframework. Here is the traceback:

Comment: Please don't put the traceback in a comment. You can edit your question and add it there. It's impossible to read as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to guess that you or someone else has altered Selenium2Library's source code on the machine running the test. Getting a traceback is the best step to troubleshoot. Use `--loglevel DEBUG` when you run your test to capture the traceback.